# All files in newly imported projects from ClearCase view marked as Hijacked in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

Every project from a certain ClearCase view that I try to import into JBoss Developer Studio 3.0.0GA comes in with every file marked as hijacked. When I view the project in ClearCase Explorer, the files are marked as expected, with only actual hijacked files marked as such. In JDS, I can manually go through the files and Undo the Hijack on them, which clears the "hijacked" badge from the icon, but afterwards I am then still unable to hijack any files. It seems that whatever mapping manages project file state between JDS and ClearCase has been corrupted.

I have both recreated my views from scratch and deleted my workspace in an attempt to clear the desynchronization, to no effect. Is there another location where the ClearCase SCM Adapter might be holding on to some settings related to this project, as unlikely as that sounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK... this was all caused by my evil arch-enemy: me.

When a view is created, files in the view folder are set to "read-only" by default, and while working outside of the ClearCase sandbox and copying files in and out manually... I set the read-only flag on the entire view to `false` in the OS. So the ClearCase SCM adapter looks at the filesystem and sees all of these writable files and thinks, "Hm, these files aren't checked out, but they're writable, so they must be hijacked."

And thus the victory goes to the enemy and his legion of red Ø badges in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The only explanation should be that, somehow, RAD changes the attributes of the file (generally the read/write attribute, but it could be also the date).

Check if there is some preferences activated in the ClearCase plugin for "auto-hijack a file when editing in disconnected mode", for instance.

Check also the version of RAD and ClearCase you are using in case a similar issue was fixed in later version (like "[Java EE Tools , PK61000, The `.compatibility` file becomes hijacked in ClearCase​®​ in RAD7](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27011586)").

Comment: @grav3nimag3: what a '`cleartool ls`' returns in one of the directories where all the files have been hijacked?

Comment: Well, RAD does change attributes sometimes, and I do get the "check-in element" pop-up when Eclipse modifies a .project setting, but I can't see anything nefarious happening with regard to file attributes.
The option you mentioned is not enabled. I should mention also that the files all go to Hijacked only after I connect to ClearCase after loading RAD.
ClearCase plugin components are up-to-date.

Comment: "ls" correctly indicates only the files which are hijacked. The mislabeling only occurs inside RAD in the package editor display, where every file has the red "hijacked" symbol on it, and through which I am unable to hijack. I can work around this by working through cc explorer only, but that's beside the point. =)

Comment: @grav3nimag3: are your `.project` and `.classpath` under the ClearCase view or outside of it in the RAD workspace? Did you see this issue before? In a previous version of RAD? The latest releases for RAD mentions (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/rad/Home) being 8.5. Version 7 dates back from 2008. I am not familiar with a "RAD 3.0.0GA". Where does it come from?

Comment: My `.project` and `.classpath` files are both in the root folder of the ClearCase view. And... brainfart on the IDE. I use several flavors here as I span several development teams. That should be JBoss Developer Studio instead of RAD. Will edit the question.